# How to make a Hierarchical filter in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame df, and I tried `ddf = df.describe()`, and got result like below.

I want to make a report based on this,

so I want to separate the mean/max/min and put them in my Word doc.

I tried many ways but unless I flat the ddf, I can not filter it based on `item`.

```
                     Absmm        Xmm        Ymm        Zmm
Node   item                                                
269.0  count  2.600000e+01  26.000000  26.000000  26.000000
       mean  -5.150000e-02   0.005423   0.027385  -0.057077
       std    9.984077e-02   0.012113   0.076432   0.090868
       min   -2.820000e-01  -0.014000  -0.012000  -0.265000
       25%   -7.250000e-02  -0.000750  -0.001750  -0.072250
       50%   -8.000000e-03   0.005000   0.000000  -0.013500
       75%    6.750000e-03   0.009750   0.012500   0.002500
       max    6.600000e-02   0.048000   0.288000   0.052000
275.0  count  2.600000e+01  26.000000  26.000000  26.000000
       mean  -8.688462e-02  -0.011000   0.035615  -0.053077
       std    1.540525e-01   0.017797   0.113538   0.125961
       min   -5.990000e-01  -0.060000  -0.016000  -0.600000
       25%   -1.015000e-01  -0.020500   0.000000  -0.078500
       50%   -2.400000e-02  -0.006500   0.001000  -0.019500
       75%   -4.250000e-03  -0.001000   0.013250   0.001000
       max    5.300000e-02   0.034000   0.567000   0.112000
```

I tried `dmean = ddf.loc[ddf.index[1] == 'mean']` or something like that,

but I just can not get what I want.

How can I get the mean value of every Node in a separate DataFrame based on filtering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close - use [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
#select by position - second level of MultiIndex
dmean = ddf.loc[ddf.index.get_level_values(1) == 'mean']
#select by level name
dmean = ddf.loc[ddf.index.get_level_values('item') == 'mean']
```

Better is use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
dmean = ddf.xs('mean', axis=0, level=1)
```

Comment: Wow, that's cool. It works. Although I do not know what happened internally, but it seems that the more function/method/attribute we know about DataFrame, the more we can work on it better :-D.